# How can i implement ReCaptcha into a Nextjs contact form?

Tags: javascript, next.js, recaptcha

So im working on a portfolio website where i have a contact form implemented for people to reach me on. I was able to connect it to SendGrid for the email transfering, but now im worried about spam. I looked everywhere online for a good solution, but i just cant seem to get ReCaptcha working in my project :(. Can someone pls help me on this and explain what i could do better?

I have tried ReCaptcha v2 and v3, but both no good. The client side programming is working fine like its supposed to, but the problem is that i cant seem to get it working in the server side. Down below is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";

export default function Contact() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    const formData = {};
    Array.from(e.currentTarget.elements).forEach((field) => {
      if (!field.name) return;
      formData[field.name] = field.value;
    });
    fetch("/api/email", {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });

    alert(
      `Bedankt voor het sturen van een bericht ${name}! Ik zal spoedig contact met je opnemen.`
    );
  }

  return (
    <main className="bg-gradient-to-b from-black to-[#434343]" id="contact">
      <section>
        <div className="flex mt-5">
          <h2 className="mx-auto text-3xl font-bold">Contact</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="flex mt-5">
          <p className="mx-auto text-center text-gray-300">
            Neem gerust contact op voor vragen of andere verzoeken!
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="grid ld:grid-cols-2 esd:grid-cols-1 sd:grid-cols-1">
          <div className="flex">
            <img
              src="/contact/mail.png"
              alt=""
              className="w-[75%] mx-auto my-auto"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex mx-32 esd:mx-5 mb-10">
            <form
              method="post"
              onSubmit={handleSubmit}
              className="mx-auto my-auto space-y-5"
            >
              <input
                type="text"
                name="naam"
                value={name}
                required
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                className="w-full rounded-full p-2 border bg-white text-black"
                placeholder="Naam"
              />
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                required
                className="w-full rounded-full p-2 border bg-white text-black"
                placeholder="Wat is je email?"
              />
              <textarea
                placeholder="Je vraag of verzoek..."
                name="bericht"
                required
                className="w-full h-40 rounded p-2 border bg-white text-black"
                maxLength={300}
              ></textarea>
              <input
                type="submit"
                className="bg-gradient-to-br from-orange-400 to-[#4ECDC4] p-2 rounded cursor-pointer"
              />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have problem on Backend side. So First, make sure you have the following environment variables in your `.env.local` file:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=<your-recaptcha-site-key>
RECAPTCHA_SECRET=<your-recaptcha-secret-key>
```

Create a new API route in your Next.js project by creating a new file called `validateRecaptcha.js` inside the `pages/api` folder. In this file, add a function to validate the reCAPTCHA response key with the secret key. This can be done using the fetch function to make a POST request to the reCAPTCHA API:

```
// pages/api/validateRecaptcha.js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { recaptchaResponse } = req.body;
  const secretKey = process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET;

  const response = await fetch(
    `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secretKey}&response=${recaptchaResponse}`,
    {
      method: "POST",
    }
  );
  const data = await response.json();

  if (data.success) {
    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false });
  }
}
```

Update your `handleSubmit` function in your Contact component to send the reCAPTCHA response key to the API route and check the response:

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const recaptchaResponse = await recaptchaRef.current.executeAsync();
  recaptchaRef.current.reset();

  // ...continue with your existing form data processing

  const response = await fetch("/api/validateRecaptcha", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ recaptchaResponse }),
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    // reCAPTCHA validation passed
    fetch("/api/email", {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });
    alert(
      `Bedankt voor het sturen van een bericht \${name}! Ik zal spoedig contact met je opnemen.`
    );
  } else {
    // reCAPTCHA validation failed
    alert("reCAPTCHA validation failed. Please try again.");
  }
}
```

Finally, make sure you have a reference to the `ReCAPTCHA` component in your Contact component and that the `sitekey` prop is set to your `NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY` environment variable:

```
const recaptchaRef = useRef();

// ...

<ReCAPTCHA
  ref={recaptchaRef}
  sitekey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}
/>
```

With these changes, your server-side reCAPTCHA validation should now work properly. When the form is submitted, the reCAPTCHA response key will be sent to the `/api/validateRecaptcha` API route, which will validate it using the reCAPTCHA secret key. If the validation is successful, the form data will be sent to the `/api/email` API route as before.

This solution uses reCAPTCHA v2 Invisible, but the same approach can be applied to reCAPTCHA v3 with some minor modifications.

Comment: I implemented the code above and it worked and i want to thank you for that, but now also when i try the captcha code it always gives me a bad response. Do you know why?

Comment: Ah nevermind, after looking again i saw that you put a "\" next to the dollar sign so it wouldnt recognize the input. After removing it, it worked as you told. Thank you so much again!